# sed to replace the middle text of a given string

Tags: sed

I have a string assigned to a variable like below

```
FHI=(01)00840682109666(21)BCR12345675VI(11)200709
```

where I want to replace the string "BCR12345675VI" with "GHI87654321VH" using sed.

```
sed -i -E -e '/FHI/s/(.{26}).(.*)/\1X\2/' /test
```

With the above sed command only the first character "B" is getting replaced with "X".

Comment: `s/BCR12345675VI/GHI87654321VH/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BCR12345675VI` has 13 characters, so actually match 13 characters.
And `X` is well, `X`, not `GHI87654321VH`. So replace for what you want to replace, not for `X`.

```
s/(.{26}).{13}(.*)/\1GHI87654321VH\2/
```

btw. `(.*)` is kind of useless - the replacement is run only over the matched *part* of the string. It may be dropped:

```
s/(.{26}).{13}/\1GHI87654321VH/
```

Comment: If I use the same in a perl script it is not replace the matched string rather it is deleting the line

Comment: and it prints like this "^AGHI87654321VH^B"